# Possible to reformat multiline method parameters to single line?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

My IDE of choice is Netbeans and whenever I make a project with existing code that was formatted in Eclipse it is harder to read for me. For example Eclipse format looks like this: [image]

As you can see it puts every parameter on a new line. There is an option for this in Netbeans aswell however it is set to "Never" by default as specified in the `Options->Editor->Formatting->Java->Wrapping->Method Parameters` setting. When I try to reformat the code in Netbeans it will not reformat this to become like this: [image]

I have over 1000 classes and wish to let the Netbeans formatter do this. Is there any way or any alternative to reformat to this style?

Comment: An alternative could be to open the code in Eclipse and tell it to format your code correctly.

Comment: You're saying that with your Netbeans config, when you **explicitly** tell it to reformat the file, it doesn't move the parameters?

Comment: Yes indeed. I press reformat code (ALT+SHIFT+F)  after explicitly specifying that it NEVER has to wrap these parameters and it will not reformat the wrapped ones. It will however never wrap new code when it gets typed.